# How to pass a form radio button value as a query parameter

Tags: microsoft-access

I am working in Access 2016 and I have a from that the user can select the training type the want to run the report on. All trainings has an option value of 1, Bloodborne has an option value of 2 and so on. I want to take the value of my form and pass it into a query so it will display all employees that took that training.

My form is View February Training and contains a option group within a frame that is called FrameAllorCurrent. My query contains the training field which I am able to filter with the following Like "68" Were 68 is the training ID from the training table.

I know I have to do something in the training field of the query along the lines of [forms]![View February Training].[FrameAllOrCurrent].Value = 2 but how do I make it so when it equals 2 it makes the training field "68" and returns all my bloodborne trainings?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have full control over the values assigned to each option in an option group (the incrementing values of `1, 2, ..., n` are merely the defaults). You can assign any numerical value by changing the `Option Value` property of the Option object, providing there are no duplicate values within the group.

This will therefore avoid the need to translate between the Option values and the parameters for your query, as you can reference the value of the Frame directly.